# Given a string, determine whether it is from an .html_safe call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails, given a string, is it possible to determine whether [.html_safe](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) has been called on that string?

Reason for asking: I'd like to write a controller unit test that verifies that html_safe has *not* been called on a particular string, in order to prove that when that string later gets rendered onto a page in a view, Rails will escape the string (avoiding possible XSS vulnerabilities).

I realize that I could instead go ahead and actually render the page in my test, and then inspect the rendered page body, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct way of doing this?

Comment: Via `string.html_safe?` maybe?

Comment: @Stefan I looked into that, but it appears to be deprecated: https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/String/html_safe%3F

Comment: There's no deprecation notice and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Ah -- I had seen the deprecation notice on Rails 2.3.8 String.html_safe? at https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe%3F, but it looks like it was moved to Object.html_safe? in later versions: https://apidock.com/rails/Object/html_safe%3F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's `html_safe?`:

```
s = 'foo'
s.html_safe? #=> false

s = 'foo'.html_safe
s.html_safe? #=> true
```

Note that an `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` reverts to unsafe if you call a "destructive" method:

```
s = 'foo'.html_safe
s.html_safe?  #=> true
s.capitalize! #=> 'Foo'
s.html_safe?  #=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

`.html_safe` actually returns not an object of type [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html), but an object of type [ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html) (which is a derived class of String).

Therefore, calling:

`my_string.is_a?(ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer)`

will return `false` only when the string is *not* the result of a call to  `.html_string`.